# How to using "find()" with populate field in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I have 2 collection in same db. I need to using find() to select only "Events" that have "team" equal "team1"

Thank you very much.

I have try to find by population field but it doesn't work.

```js
 This is my Event schema
    const Event = mongoose.model('Event', new mongoose.Schema({
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            min: 3
        },
        eventType: {
            type: String,
            lowercase: true
        },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now()
        },
        venue: String,
        country: String,
        callLog: {
            type: String,
            max: 1000
        },
        eventImgUrl: [String],
        editedBy : {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        timestamp: {
            type: String, 
            default: Date.now()
        }
    }));
```

```js
This is my User schema
    const User = mongoose.model('User', new mongoose.Schema({
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            min: 3,
            lowercase: true
        },
        name: String,
        email: String,
        team: String,
        role: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['admin', 'creator', 'viewer']
        }
    }));
```

```js
This is my Controller
    const events = await Event.find()
        .populate({ path: 'editedBy', select: ['name', 'team']});

    res.send(events);
```

Answer (score 0):

To `find` all `Events` that have a `team` of `"team1"`:

```
const team1Events = await Event.find({ team: "team1" });
```

Comment: It doesn't work because "team" property is in User's schema not Event's schema.

Answer (score 0):

`select` just specifies the fields returned. You need to use [populate match](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate):

```
await Event.find()
    .populate({ path: 'editedBy', match: { yourField: 'yourmatch' }});
```